# USB camera is not getting detected

Tags: android, camera, usb, qualcomm

I am working on Qualcomm 820 board, On which I am interfacing one USB  web camera VF0250 with android Nougat Source code.
I am able to load the uvc driver, and when I am connecting the USB camera, a node is getting created named /dev/video2, but when I am using an application named HAL3-test-app which is in the Android source code, it is giving number of cameras equal to 0, I am not able to understand why it is giving this, is there any dependency remaining from the kernel side to enable this camera??

Comment: Android does not support plug and play USB cameras.

Comment: When i am using the camerafi app and neuralassembly-simplewebcam app, preview is coming....means camerafi app works directly but i need to load uvc driver for the neuralassembly-simplewebcam app.....
How they are working...

Comment: maybe this is of help: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/libhardware/+/master/modules/usbcamera

Answer (score 0):

You need to load kernel modules uvcvideo.ko "USB Video class" but sometimes this is not sufficient.